# how to make React.useContext work inside a SweetAlert 2 Modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweet Alert 2 with https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content enhancer to create some modals with functionality in my app, but I've found that the only way to pass data into the swal modal is by using props:

```
    MySwal.fire({
      html: <SaveDialog schema={schema} reload={refetch}/>
    });
```

In the app I use a lot the useContext hook, in fact, those props I'm passing into the modal are already exposed in a context. When trying to use useContext on the react component rendered in the modal it won't get any of the values in the context because the swal modal is rendered outside of the react component tree, thus making the context provider higher in the tree unreachable within the modal component.

I know it's possible to wrap the component like:

```
<SomeProvider><SaveDialog schema={schema} reload={refetch}/></SomeProvider>
```

And that would work for things inside the modal itself, but that would be just another instance of the provider, that's not linked in any way to the previous instance, thus not having the right values either.
I also know that's not possible to render the swal modal as a child of a existing component in the tree (this has to do with the modal being a different ReactDOM.render). There is any way make the context provider reachable to the modal component?